# Install and Configure Oracle 11g using c# program

Tags: oracle

I need to create a windows application program using c# which will allow me to install oracle client 11g and also configure ODBC automatically with just one click, as my customers have limitations in technology and hence the installation and configuration is very difficult.

Is it possible and also if you could help with some code reference?

Answer (score 1):

For Oracle client you can use [Installation using Response Files](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e24187/advance.htm).
Your C# program can generate response file and run installer with particular command line options.